# Does anyone have links to a simple sample web site using SubSonic?

Tags: c#, sql-server, subsonic

I'm developing a new admin website to update several tables.  There is no complicated logic involved (at the moment).

The website will be built using VS 2008 C# (3.5 framework) and will have a SQL Server 2008 db.

We've decided to look into using SubSonic and I've already set up the the basic scaffolds to input test data.

Does anyone know where I could find a simple example showing the standard Select/Insert/Update/Deleting code when using SubSonic and how best we can make use of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SubSonic project has some code examples on their web site ([select queries](http://subsonicproject.com/querying/select-queries/), [using active record](http://subsonicproject.com/active-record/using-active-record/) and [stored procedures](http://subsonicproject.com/querying/stored-procedures/), for instance. Google also provides a [good amount of samples](http://www.google.se/search?q=subsonic+example).